# will_paginate links not showing in the browser or in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I just installed will_paginate and it seems to be working fine except is not displaying the links at the bottom of the page. Here is my controller:

```
    def index
        @projects = Project.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
        @user = User.new

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: @projects }
         end 
    end
```

and this is in my index.html.erb:

```
<% will_paginate @projects %>
        <% @projects.each do |project| %>

            <div class ="col-sm-3 project">

            <div id="project-index-pic">
                <%= link_to image_tag(project.url), project_path(project), class: "project-index-pic" %>
            </div>

       // .....more stuff ....

<%end%>
```

As I said, it seems to be working as far as displaying the proper amount of results (9) on the first page, and if I change that to 2 or 3 it responds accordingly. I am just not getting the links at the bottom of the page to take me to the next 9 results. In other threads people seem to see html elements associated with the will_paginate but I don't. I ran the troubleshooting lines in console:

```
[1] giving_tree(main)> defined? WillPaginate
=> "constant"
```

and:

```
[2] giving_tree(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.respond_to? :paginate
=> true
```

So that looks good. Checked the docs and a couple threads and I just don't see what I am missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's the little things.

```
<% will_paginate @projects %>
```

should have been:

```
<%= will_paginate @projects %>
```